# JavaScript on hover effects not working on child links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this navigation bar that I got a lot of help with yesterday and it's looking really nice, I got help to create some JQuery to show a new bar on the click of a link, I tried to replace the on click event to on hover, and at first the new div would appear, but then when I go to select a link, the div disappears again. I tried to change the script to remain when the child links are hovered on, like this:

```
$('.navbar ul li:nth-child(2) a').hover(function() {
    $(".additional").slideToggle()
});

$('.navbar ul li:nth-child(2) a').hover(function() {
    $(".additional child(*)").slideToggle()
});
```

[This is the fiddle of the (almost) working navigation bar](http://jsfiddle.net/Jammizzle/a6qf620x/18/)

So this is the HTML That I use to throw the Navigation Bar together, with some CSS to do the colours and other small adjustments

```
<header>
        <div class="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li style="float: left"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contract">Contracts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#other">Other</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#release">Release Notes</a></li>
                    <li> <a target="_blank" href="http://www.phpartnership.com">Pinnacle Health Partnership</a></li>
                </ul>
                    <ul class="additional">
                        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://lscm.pharmoutcomes.org/celesio">Lloyds Pharmacy</a></li>
                        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://contracts.pharmoutcomes.org/superdrug/home">Superdrug Pharmacy</a></li>
                        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://contracts.pharmoutcomes.org/daylewis/home">Day Lewis Pharmacy</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
</header>
```

Comment: The content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Without your HTML, the question is meaningless. Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) let you put a runnable example right here in your question.

Comment: I'll edit the question, my apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem occurs, because you don't specify in your JavaScript code that the child must stay open, when the parent loses hover, but the child has it.

To achieve that try altering your code to:

```
var childHovered = false;

  $('.navbar ul li:nth-child(2) a').hover(function() {
        $(".additional").slideDown();
    },
  function() {
    if (!childHovered) {
        $(".additional").slideUp();
    }
  });

  $(".additional").hover(function() {
    childHovered = true;
  },
  function() {
    $(this).slideUp();
  });
```

Check out [this update](http://jsfiddle.net/a6qf620x/24/) of your fiddle for a more visual representation.

Comment: When attempting to select `Day Lewis Pharmacy`, the menu disappears

Comment: This looks great! The only issue is, If I hover onto the child classes a tad fast, the div will get caught in a loop of constantly opening and closing

Comment: On my local project this looks (almost) perfect! The only issue is as @wmash mentioned, I can't select over Day Lewis Pharmacy

Comment: You're a star! Thank you so much! I really need to start learning how to do basic JavaScript

Comment: @JamieBelcher please look at https://www.codecademy.com/learn on FREE courses on getting started with JS and jQuery :)

Comment: I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your codes to this, Think were collapsing when you were hovering over the second link of additional class.

```
$('.navbar ul li:nth-child(2)').mouseenter(function() {
        $(".additional").slideDown();
    });

  $('.additional').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).slideUp();
    });
```

Comment: They still collapse when I go to hover over them, I usually try to steer clear of JS and Jquery so this is all new to me!

Comment: @JamieBelcher when you hover on contracts link your .additional slidesdown. Same as when cursor leave out from that div slideup back to it's position.

Comment: @frnt  it work certain approach ,but the child div will still showing if you not mouseout on it.

Comment: @ChitThiriMaung if you mouse-out from that particular div it hides that div.

Comment: my point is if user hover on 'Contracts' , show the child div  and user keep going on other like ''About Us,Other" the child div is keep showing.

Comment: Yes because my code stated that when my cursor leaves .additional it should slideUp.